# How to change the link of product menu from wordpress admin panel

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using Woo-Commerce and after activating it a new tab appears with name product I want to change the link of that product tab like if anyone click on that button it will be redirected to the front side add product link instead of Woo-commerce add product page can some one please help me.

[image: Image will eloborate what I am trying to say]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the admin navigation using the `$menu` global var. The following will accomplish what you're after

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_edit_admin_menu');
function my_plugin_edit_admin_menu() {
    global $menu, $submenu;
    foreach ($menu as $menuKey => $menuItem)
        if ($menuItem[0] == 'Products')
            $menu[$menuKey][2] = 'https://google.com/'; // wtv link you want

    // UPDATE:
    // remove the sub menu as well (note the GLOBAL var define above)
    $submenu['edit.php?post_type=product'] = ''; 
    unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=product']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @David it saved a day can you please tell that how can I hide the submenu as well of this product menu

Comment: You may use `$submenu` to edit the submenu. I've updated the code with it above.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked and saved most of my time Thank you once again.